# Discrete sets and linear maps

Tags: general-topology

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a discrete set and $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$, with $k<n$, a surjective linear map. Can you ensure that $f(A)$ is discrete?

I think this is true but I haven't been able to prove it. This has been my attemp so far:

Let $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in A$. Since $A$ is discrete, there is some open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that  $U\cap A=\{x\}$. Now, since $f$ is an open map, we have that $f(U)$ is an open neighbourhood of y. But now I am not able to prove that $f(U)\cap f(A)=\{y\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't prove it, since it is false. Just take$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R^2&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&x+\sqrt 2y.\end{array}$$Then $f$ is surjective and $f(\mathbb Z^2)$ is *not* discrete.

Comment: Excuse me, I edit the question

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{q_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be the set of rational numbers indexed by $\mathbb{N}$—i.e., each rational number $q_k$ has been given a natural-numbered "label", $k$, determined by an arbitrary bijection $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$.  Working in $\mathbb{R}^2$, consider $A = \{(q_k, k) \ | \ k \in \mathbb{N} \}$, which is discrete as any two distinct points are separated from each other vertically by at least $1$ unit of distance.  Now let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be the projection map $(x,y) \mapsto x$.  You can check that $f$ is both linear and surjective, and notice that $f(A) = \mathbb{Q}$, which is no longer discrete: for instance, any open ball centered at $0 \in \mathbb{Q}$ contains (infinitely many) rational numbers $1/n$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.